# Validation Error : Unable to instantiate GPT4AllEmbeddings Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, large-language-model, gpt4all

I am encountering an issue while trying to create an instance of GPT4AllEmbeddings. However i keep receiving the following error

```
Cell In[15], line 1
----> 1 vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents = splits, embeddings = GPT4AllEmbeddings())
      2 retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_type = 'similarity', search_kwargs = {'k':6})
      3 retrieved_docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents("What are you ?")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py:341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for GPT4AllEmbeddings
__root__
  Unable to instantiate model (type=value_error)
```

here is the relevant code snippet

```
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents = splits, embeddings = GPT4AllEmbeddings())
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_type = 'similarity', search_kwargs = {'k':6})
retrieved_docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents("What is Young Decade ?")
print(len(retrieved_docs))
print(retrieved_docs[0].page_content)
```

how to solve this error?